# Knockout - dictionary, set key as variable value with mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have edited this to be more concise and fro requests as yesterday i was somewhat despondent from a day of fails..

I am binding my select list(type_of_cover) to a controller action(FetchPolicyPlans) where I am successfully able to bind the dictionary values to the key and value fields.

My problem lies with the form post where i only want the dictionary Key, as the value, to be passed with the form post.

```
**HTML**

<div class="instant-quote-form">
    @using(Html.BeginForm("Index","thank-you-quote", FormMethod.Post, new {@id="instant-quote"}))
    { 
///some more code
<select class="form_details" name="type_of_cover" id="form-type" style="margin-top: -1px;"
                        data-bind="options: PolicyPlans,
                                    optionsValues: 'Key',
                                    optionsText: 'Value',
                                        optionsCaption: '-- Please Select --',
                                        value: SelectedPolicyPlan"></select>


**JS**
function QuoteViewModel() {
var self = this;
self.SelectedPolicyPlan = ko.observable();
self.PolicyPlans = ko.observableArray();

 $.ajax({
        url: '/InstantQuote/FetchPolicyPlans',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        async: false,
        data: ko.toJSON({ productId: ProductId() }),
        success: function (plans) {                
            self.PolicyPlans(plans);
        },
        error: function () { QuoteError(); }        
    });        
}
```

ko.applyBindings(new QuoteViewModel());

```
**Controller**
 public JsonResult FetchPolicyPlans(int productId)
    {
        Constants.ProductTypes productType;
        Enum.TryParse(productId.ToString(), true, out productType);

        KeyValuePair<int, string>[] plans = MvcApplication._vertigoService.FetchApiPolicyPlans(productType);
        return Json(plans);
    }
```

Comment: All this goes into the client side of the project. It's important to show how you're currently setting up your bindings, what your data looks like, and how you're sending the object(s) off to your receiving Controller. Chances are, there is a simple solution...spend time on your question if you want someone to spend time making an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many errors in your code as I can see:

1. VehicleMakes is not defined.
2. What is self? try "var self=this;" in the QuoteViewModel at the top of everything.

One more thing... Try sending data with ajax call rather then posting the form. This way you can create a method in viewmodel and post the SelectedPolicyPlan value to the server and then you can redirect to view.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ashish. 
Pardon the vehicleMakes, i have included the correct ajax call now. 
I had originally used the ajax call to do the post, however i thought that there would be way to do it with the mvc form post too.

Comment: You can use knockout function postJson. Add the following Save method to your view model:

function AppViewModel() {
    self = this;

    self.firstName = ko.observable(initialData.FirstName);
    self.lastName = ko.observable(initialData.LastName);

    self.Save = function(){
        var jsonData = ko.toJSON(self);
        ko.utils.postJson(location.href, {person: jsonData});
    };
}   
Also you can add button to your view:

<button data-bind="click: Save" ></button>

Comment: Thanks so far Ashish, but there must be some way to set only the value thats posted with the form to the dictionary key value with some sort of binding method. The code at the top is only an extract relating to my question. Should i list it all?

Comment: Ok then, no solutions .. I have a work around for this, it is NOT ideal.
But this is what i added to my form(html):
<div data-bind="with: SelectedPolicyPlan()" style="display:none;">                       
                       <input type="hidden"  name="selectedPlanId" data-bind="value: Key" >
                    </div>

Comment: It will be good if you can create a working sample on jsfiddle. I will check there and will modify the code.